# Select and update; SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to loop table `tab_A` entry by entry and update table `tab_B` according to content in each returned entry:

```
SELECT item, regBy, MAX(regTime) AS latestUpdateTime
FROM tab_A
GROUP BY item, regBy;
```

The result must be looped entry by entry and the following UPDATE must be performed for each entry:

```
UPDATE tab_B
SET lastUpdated = "data from latestUpdateTime in SQL above"
lastUpdBy = "data from regBy in SQL above"
WHERE item = "data from item in SQL above"
```

I'm not familiar with Transact SQL, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the **table structures?** Column names, their datatypes, possible constraints etc. Also: which **VERSION** of SQL Server are you using?? 7.0? 2000? 2005? 2008? 2008 R2??

Comment: Generally in Sql you want to think how to update sets of records not loop through them.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn a regular select statement into an update statement quite easily by replacing the `SELECT *` with `UPDATE table...`

This allows you to first verify what will get updated before actually applying the update.

**Select statement**

```
SELECT *
FROM   tab_B b
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  item
                  , regBy
                  , MAX(regTime) AS latestUpdateTime
         FROM     tab_A
         GROUP BY 
                  item
                  , regBy
       ) a ON a.item = b.item
```

**Update statement**

```
UPDATE tab_B
SET    lastUpdated = a.latestUpdateTime
       , lastUpdBy = a.regBy
FROM   tab_B b
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  item
                  , regBy
                  , MAX(regTime) AS latestUpdateTime
         FROM     tab_A
         GROUP BY 
                  item
                  , regBy
       ) a ON a.item = b.item
```

Another way to verify the update and depending on your version would be by starting a transaction and using the `OUTPUT` clause.

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE tab_B
SET    lastUpdated = a.latestUpdateTime
       , lastUpdBy = a.regBy
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
FROM   tab_B b
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  item
                  , regBy
                  , MAX(regTime) AS latestUpdateTime
         FROM     tab_A
         GROUP BY 
                  item
                  , regBy
       ) a ON a.item = b.item

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server **2005 or newer**, you can do something like this:

```
;WITH TableAData AS
(
   SELECT 
       item, regBy, regTime,
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY regTime DESC)
   FROM dbo.tab_A
)
UPDATE dbo.tab_B
SET 
    lastUpdated = a.regTime,
    lastUpdBy = a.regby
FROM TableAData a    
WHERE
    tab_B.item = a.item 
    AND a.RowNum = 1
```

Basically, this CTE (Common Table Expression) orders your data in such a way that for each `item`, a `RowNum` is calculated (with the most recent one getting `RowNum = 1`).

With this, you can easily update your `tab_B` in a single statement - no row-by-agonizing-row looping needed!